# Gnuplot fillstyle pattern with word function gives error

Tags: for-loop, gnuplot

I am plotting a file with different columns and I am using the for loop of gnuplot. I want to completely control the look of my graph so I use `set line style` to control the color of my lines. I want to do the same with the pattern fills but it seems that it is not possible with gnuplot.

So far I have come to that solution, which does not work as well, for unknown reasons:

```
set terminal cairolatex standalone pdf
set style line 2 linecolor rgbcolor "#F9E0B0" linewidth 2 pt 13
# etc ... up to 10

pat="0 2 4 7 2 4 7 2 4 7" ## An attempt to define the pattern style I want
set style fill pattern 1 border ## this control the first pattern, then the next ones are incremented but it cannot control each index

set output "myplot.tex"
plot for [i=2:10] "myfile.dat" index 0 u i:xtic(1) fillstyle pattern int(word(pat, i)) ls i ti columnheader ## The color is controlled according to me via the linestyle, but the fillstyle does not work

## An alternate solution giving a little bit of control but not fully satisfactory since I want to avoid the pattern 3
# plot for [i=2:10] "myfile.dat" index 0 u i:xtic(1) fillstyle pattern i%3+1 ls i ti columnheader 
unset output
```

With this solution I get the following error: `unexpected or unrecognized token`

Any idea why word fails after fillstyle pattern, or does anyone have an idea on how to specify for each data the pattern?

EDIT: I am using gnuplot 5.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parser is expecting the entity immediately following "fillstyle" to be a number, but it doesn't recognize int("foo") as a number.  That's a bug. You can work around this by using instead the syntax

```
fillstyle pattern 0+word(pat,i)
```